# How to put events back to Kinesis Firehose ater a AWS Lambda transformed them?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using a Lambda function to transform events and now I want to put them back into the Kinsesis Firehose to send them to Splunk.

For that I used a handler to get the Events into the function.

```java
public class Application implements RequestHandler<KinesisFirehoseEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(KinesisFirehoseEvent event, Context context) {
        EventService eventService = new EventService();
        eventService.process(event);
        return null;
    }
```

After transformation I have this data model. It is equivalent to the status model in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) which should be used as response for the Firehose stream. So that it can sort out failed or corrupted events.

```java
public class Message {

    private final String recordId;

    private String data;

    private final ProcessingResult result;
}
```

Now I would like to send the records back. At the moment it looks like that.

```java
    public void send(Message data, String streamArn) {
        Record record = new Record();
        //Add Message
        PutRecordBatchRequest putRecordBatchRequest = new PutRecordBatchRequest();
        //add record
        putRecordBatchRequest.setDeliveryStreamName(streamArn);
        firehoseClient.putRecordBatch(putRecordBatchRequest);
        //send
    }
```

I saw that the Record representation in the [Python example](https://github.com/amazon-archives/serverless-app-examples/blob/master/python/kinesis-firehose-process-record-python/lambda_function.py) is different from the properties of the RecordBuilder which only needs a data property.

Could I just use a HashMap to do the representation of the StatusModel and afterwards do a Base64 encoding to send them or is there a other method to do it correctly.

Does anybody have experiences on how to do the Response after a event has been transformed?

Comment: You dont need to call PutRecord or PutRecordBatch API to return records back to firehose from transformation lambda. Just use "return" as shown in python example.

Comment: Do you know if a mapping to JSON would be enough?

Comment: can you please clarify your question?

Comment: The return model says that the return value has to be in a certain model. How can I archive this, is there already a ModellClass in the AWS library or can I just pass a JSON which has this structure

Comment: The required model is given in AWS document. But I dont think there is different ModelClass in java sdks for this. You can try JSON structure similar to python example